# Is there a way to find SDK version that was used to compile the AS3 app, from within that app?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, flashdevelop

We need to branch the logic flow in our AS3 application depending on the SDK version that it was compiled with. Is there a way to know what SDK version was used to compile the AS3 app, from within that app?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the framework version from the [FlexVersion](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/core/FlexVersion.html)
 class:

```
trace(FlexVersion.CURRENT_VERSION);
```

This will return a uint containing the version. such as 0x04060000 (sdk 4.6)

You could also use [other constants](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/core/FlexVersion.html#constantSummary) of FlexVersion to compare against. eg:

```
trace("Is it v3? ", FlexVersion.CURRENT_VERSION==FlexVersion.VERSION_3_0);
```

Comment: Does one need to include the whole flex core to get this working? Our app is very small, pure AS3 one of mere 25kb (we would like it to stay there and do not grow anymore).

Comment: Looks like the last SDK version that supported mx.core.FlexVersion was 4.1. Doesn't seem to be available in 4.6.0.

Comment: looks like i didnt pay enough attention to your question - i saw "sdk" and assumed you meant Flex SDK. What sdk are you referring to? Do you mean Flash Player version?

Comment: To rephrase the question I would say now if it is possible to differentiate between compilers (they come with SDKs and probably do include it partially - not sure).

Comment: which compiler/sdk are you talking about? Are you building an AIR app?

Comment: No, not AIR, but for Flash Player.

Comment: FP doesnt have an sdk. Do you mean FP version( eg: 11.8?)

Comment: Whatever... :) FlexVersion.CURRENT_VERSION would have been perfect if it was available. But it's not here in Flash Builder + Flex SDK 4.6.0.